# Getting same DeviceToken back from APNs in Development and Production

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I've been pulling my hair out for the last three days trying to get this to work so I figured I'd better ask for help before it's too late.

I'm trying to get Push Notifications setup to work with our iOS app but I run into a wall when I try and send a push message with the device token that I get back from "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken". It's all works fine with my debug build but when I try to do the same thing in production I get a error back from the APNS saying that my device token in invalid.

I've made sure to create what I need in this order

1. first I created an AppID,
2. then enabled Push Notifications
3. then I created seperate APNs SSL Certificates for Development and
   Production
4. finally I created Provisioning Profiles for Development and
   Production

Along the way I download the certs and provisioning profiles and installed them.

I've done this four times so far and yet I'm still getting the same error.

One thing that doesn't look quite right is that I get the exact same device token back from "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" regardless if I'm doing a debug or release build. From what I've read online that is not nessarily wrong but maybe that's the issue?

Also, I'm creating the Push Cert and the Distribution Cert with the same private key. Is that right?

any help is greatly appricated!

Comment: How are you distributing the production build? How do you determine what device token you get back from didRegisterForRemote....?

Comment: 1. I'm pushing a release build directly onto my phone from Xcode. 2. I just check that the aps-environment value in my Distribution provisioning profile is set to "production". In the Development provisioning profile the aps-environment value is set to "development". Is that wrong?

Comment: If you have your phone running from xcode you are running a dev build, even if its set to production as far as I know. There is no way to get push notifications when plugged into xcode - you need to be running an ad hoc production build using something like testflight.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be getting the same device token in both the debug and release builds. That's definietly the reason you are getting an invalid token error when pushing to the production env.

You should check the aps-environment entitlement of your production provisioning profile, to make sure its value is `Distribution`.